# Approach for handling internal scheduling and global ticketing system in one JIRA instance

Tags: jira, scheduling

We have a following setup in my organization:

1. Company-wide JIRA instance (over 3000 users I think)
2. Organization JIRA instance (less than 200 hundred) with Tempo planner

The reason we have an Organization JIRA instance is that we need the [Tempo planner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211881/tempo-planner?hosting=datacenter&tab=pricing), **but only for max 50 people**, and it seems if we wanted to add it to the company-wide instance, it would cost over 8k dollars, and we wouldn't even want to use this for over 2950 people.
So, somebody decided it would be smarter to host a little JIRA just for ourselves and pay less for the add-on.

However, we now think it would be good if everybody in the company could have access to our JIRA, in order to create issues and view & communicate on their tickets (rather than manage that via other channels).

Any idea how could we handle it?

- Could we buy Tempo planner for company-wide JIRA and make it available only to certain people, and pay only for those?
- Could we add *something* to our little organization JIRA that would allow everybody in the company to log & view tickets (having SSO etc.?)

Comment: This is basically a Tempo licensing issue. Their page explicitly states that the license price is determined by total number of users, not by those who actually use it. You might want to discuss it with them. Good luck!